# choosing perfect view engine for spring mvc projects

Tags: user-interface, spring-mvc, viewengine

I was thinking to develop web project on spring mvc. But somehow I was stuck on developing view engine. I was little bit familiar with asp.net mvc. I know their view engine are very clean and nice. I worked with  razor view. I liked it. Now my point, is there anything like in spring framework or is there anything that can be incorporate with spring framework. I know about jstl, jsp and once I tried with sitemesh but somehow messed up.

Can anyone help to figure out a good way to find view engine which can be incorporated with spring mvc project so that my ui can be rich and much cleaner and easy to integrate. 
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Which technology did you end up going with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Spring Faces](http://www.springsource.org/faces), [Web Flow](http://www.springsource.org/webflow) and [BlazeDS](http://www.springsource.org/spring-flex) are your choices for RIA technologies. For traditional MVC, you still have plain [JSP/JSTL, Velocity and FreeMarker](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/view.html). If one of these doesn't fit your needs, I suggest using another platform.